# Pycharm Django Syncdb MySQLdb not found

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I've started using Pycharm for my Django development and have come to this error. I know that my MySQLdb is working as I can import it when I try in python shell and I can run syncdb commands on the command line. 
My question is what do I need to add to Pycharm to make MySQLdb recognized. I am working on a Mac OS X if that makes any difference. Do I need to add something to my manage.py or does it need to be added to the Pycharm's Preferences? or it is it something different.
Thanks for the help guys.

Here is the Error I'm getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 21, in <module>
        run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
        fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
        mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "/Users/Brandon/PycharmProjects/Database_assignment/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
        klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
        module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
        from django.db import models
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
        return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
        backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
        return import_module('.base', backend_name)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I think there is some problem with the way the enviroment has been setup on pycharm. The python interpreter pycharm is using does not probably have mysqldb installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

pip install mysql-python

I think in Pycharm you can install the packages through GUI. But in essence you need to install mysql-python

You may need to do sudo pip install mysql-python if you are getting "Permission denied messages"

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm defines the interpreter to use for each project, so you'll need to double-check the project is set to use either:

1. The virtualenv you have setup
2. The system Python, if you're not using a virtualenv (which you should be).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3, mysql-python won't install because it doesn't support python 3. Use mysqlclient instead. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#id9).